# Получить ID из View

Tags: java, android, view

Требуется получить ID объекта в виде String из объекта View.

Можно получить id, используя

```
view.getId()
```

Но тогда возвращается число, а мне требуется иное:

так:

```
 R.id.textView
```

или так

```
tetView
```

Comment: Объясните зачем вам это?

Comment: Оно так не работает. R.id.textView - это переменная в автогенерируем классе R. А без диких хаков в яве обращаться к переменным, в рантайме задавая им имя - нельзя и не надо. Вы решаете вашу задачу совсем не так как надо - опишите конкретную задачу, а не попытку её решения.

Comment: Я ответ дал, это возможно. Но присоединюсь к коллегам: не должно быть необходимости получать id вьюхи в виде строки.

Comment: Имеется множество кликабельных элементов TextView с практически идентичным содержимым. Вот и хочу привязать содержимое элементов TextView к массиву. Т.к. элементов много и выполняются идентичные действия для них, то использовал 1 Listener. Вот в нем и нужно определить какой id у элемента TextView, чтоб знать к какому элементу массива присваивать содержимое

Comment: В теории единый слушатель распределяет действия в `switch(view.getId()){case R.id.textView1: someAction(); break; case R.id.textView2: anotherAction(); break;}` etc

Comment: Задача понятная, но лучше сравнивать id элемента (из getId()) c константами из R.id. Это избавит от ошибок.

Answer (score 1):

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```

или

```
getResources().getResourceName(int resid);
```

Comment: Благодарю, верхний вариант подошел =)